# Join spatial features with dataframe by id with inconsistent format

Tags: r, merge, geometry, spatial, shapefile

Hello everyone I was hoping I could get some help with this issue:

I have shapefile with 2347 features that correspond to 3172 units, perhaps when the original file was created there were some duplicated geometries and they decided to arrange them like this:

```
Feature gis_id
 1        "1"     
 2        "2"     
 3       "3,4,5"
 4        "6,8"     
 5        "7"     
 6       "9,10,13"
```

... like that until the 3172 units and 2347 features

On the other side my data table has 72956 observations (about 16 columns) with data corresponding to the gis_id from the shapefile. However, this table has a unique gis_id per observation

```
head(hru_ls)
  jday  mon  day   yr  unit  gis_id    name  sedyld   tha sedorgn   kgha sedorgp   kgha surqno3   kgha lat3no3   kgha
1   365   12   31 1993     1       1 hru0001        0.065          0.861          0.171          0.095              0
2   365   12   31 1993     2       2 hru0002        0.111          1.423          0.122          0.233              0
3   365   12   31 1993     3       3 hru0003        0.024          0.186          0.016          0.071              0
4   365   12   31 1993     4       4 hru0004        6.686         16.298          1.040          0.012              0
5   365   12   31 1993     5       5 hru0005       37.220        114.683          6.740          0.191              0
6   365   12   31 1993     6       6 hru0006        6.597         30.949          1.856          0.021              0
  surqsolp   kgha usle   tons sedmin   ---- tileno3   ----
1           0.137           0         0.010              0
2           0.041           0         0.009              0
3           0.014           0         0.001              0
4           0.000           0         0.175              0
5           0.000           0         0.700              0
6           0.000           0         0.227              0
```

With multiple records for each unit (20 years data)

I would like to merge the geometry data of my shapefile to my data table. I've done this before with `sp::merge` I think, but with a shapefile that did not have multiple id's per geometry/feature.

Is there a way to condition the merging so it gives each feature from the data table the corresponding geometry according to if it has any of the values present on the gis_id field from the shapefile?

Comment: Hi @KrakensDaughter, did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very intriguing question, so I gave it a shot. My answer is probably not the quickest or most concise way of going about this, but it works (at least for your sample data). Notice that this approach is fairly sensitive to the formatting of the data in `shapefile$gis_id` (see regex).

```
# your spatial data
shapefile <- data.frame(feature = 1:6, gis_id = c("1", "2", "3,4,5", "6,8", "7", "9,10,13"))
# your tabular data
hru_ls <- data.frame(unit = 1:6, gis_id = paste(1:6))

# loop over all gis_ids in your tabular data
# perhaps this could be vectorized?
gis_ids <- unique(hru_ls$gis_id)
for(id in gis_ids){

  # Define regex to match gis_ids
  id_regex <- paste0("(,|^)", id, "(,|$)")

  # Get row in shapefile that matches regex
  searchterm <- lapply(shapefile$gis_id, function(x) grepl(pattern = id_regex, x = x))
  rowmatch <- which(searchterm == TRUE)

  # Return shapefile feature id that maches tabular gis_id
  hru_ls[hru_ls$gis_id == id, "gis_feature_id"] <- shapefile[rowmatch, "feature"]
}
```

Since you didn't provide the geometry fields in your question, I just matched on `Feature` in your spatial data. You could either add an additional step that merges based on `Feature`, or replace `"feature"` in `shapefile[rowmatch, "feature"]` with your geometry fields.